# I can't binding event in a tag during implementing pjax

Tags: javascript, pjax

I was implementing pjax. However, the href attribute on the link tag still works. preventDefault() with addEventListener; I also tried to apply return false; as well. How can I prevent the href tag from working?

My code:
(link is a predefined function that sends pjax as an argument value. It is simply sent, so it doesn't matter here.)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(addEventListener('click', function(){
    preventDefault();
    link(location.pathname);
};);
```

Comment: Isnt it e => e.preventDefault() ... surprised you don't get errors in the console

Comment: There's no error but e.preventDefault() isn't work. I want to call link function when user click a tag. And I added attribute href for non-javascript devices. But, when I click a tag, I want to only call function link but a tag is work.

Comment: so, `function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...etc` makes no difference ... I'm still surprised that `preventDefault()` like that doesn't throw an error though